TD_Smote function in Teradata
I am attempting to run the Smote function in Teradata uisng the code below which is taken directly from the terdata guidance document.
SELECT * FROM TD_SMOTE (
      ON iris_enc_sample AS InputTable PARTITION BY ANY
      USING
      NumberOfNeighbors(5)
      IDColumn('id')
      MinorityClass('3')
      ResponseColumn('species')
      InputColumns('sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width')
      OversamplingFactor(2)
      SamplingStrategy('smote')
) AS dt;

but it keeps giving the error sytanx error expected something like a "," between the word td_smote and '('
CREATE MULTISET TABLE iris_enc_sample ,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     MAP = TD_MAP1
     (
      id INTEGER,
      sepal_length FLOAT,
      sepal_width FLOAT,
      petal_length FLOAT,
      petal_width FLOAT,
      species INTEGER)
PRIMARY INDEX ( id );
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (78,6.0,2.9,4.5,1.5,2);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (141,6.9,3.1,5.1,2.3,3);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (97,6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,2);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (13,4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,1);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (112,6.8,3.0,5.5,2.1,3);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (89,5.5,2.5,4.0,1.3,2);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (7,5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,1);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (85,6.0,3.4,4.5,1.6,2);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (5,5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,1);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (83,6.0,2.7,5.1,1.6,2);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (39,5.1,3.4,1.5,0.2,1);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (35,5.0,3.2,1.2,0.2,1);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (94,5.6,2.7,4.2,1.3,2);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (27,5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,1);
INSERT INTO iris_enc_sample (id,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species) VALUES (111,6.4,2.7,5.3,1.9,3);


SELECT * FROM TD_SMOTE (
      ON iris_enc_sample AS InputTable PARTITION BY ANY
      USING
      NumberOfNeighbors(5)
      IDColumn('id')
      MinorityClass('3')
      ResponseColumn('species')
      InputColumns('sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width')
      OversamplingFactor(2)
      SamplingStrategy('smote')
) AS dt;

expecting the function TD_SMOTE TO RUN

Most likely that function is not available on your instance.  You can replace select * from TD_SMOTE ( with something silly like select * from ThisIsNotReal (..., and you'll get the same error.

I believe this function is only available in database version 20.00 and later.
